# Clause Where Python using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

what is the pandas equivalent of

`SELECT Column2 
FROM DF
WHERE column3 ="value"`

when we are using dataframe please

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` and a conditional statement on a Dataframe to select out relevant information, similar to a where clause. You can pull out your desired column(s) using a second argument to `loc`, e.g.

```
df.loc[df[column3]==“value”, [column2]]
```

Comment: No, you mustn't use two levels of selection, especially when it can be done with 1.

Comment: I’ve amended my answer to only use one level of selection.

Comment: hello!! It works perfectly now but to verifiy 2 colums value .. I TRYIED This but it doesn't work  ....`df.loc[df["column3"]== "value" & df["column1"] == "value2", ['column2']]` .. Have you any ideas please